# Strange error when trying to install ipython

Tags: python, ipython

I ran

```
sudo pip install ipython
```

And got the following error after the command line got most of the way through the installation process:

```
 Running setup.py install for scandir ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import 
setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-build-  
szsEFp/scandir/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)
(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', 
'\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record 
/tmp/pip-iOop0U-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-
managed --compile:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py",   
line 12, in <module>
        import setuptools.version
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools/version.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    import packaging.requirements
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/packaging/requirements.py", line 59, in <module>
    MARKER_EXPR = originalTextFor(MARKER_EXPR())("marker")
TypeError: __call__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, 
tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-build-
szsEFp/scandir/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)
(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', 
'\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record 
/tmp/pip-iOop0U-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-
managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-
szsEFp/scandir/
```

What's going on?

Comment: I don't know what's wrong there, but the easiest way I know to install iPython, and the rest of the Jupyter stack, along with other hard to install dependencies is to use [Anaconda Python](https://www.continuum.io/downloads). I like it a lot.

Comment: Try `sudo easy_install ipython` instead... it seems to work better on the mac. I'm pretty sure you've gotten yourself into a case where you have parts of two different version of setuptools installed; if easy_install doesn't work either, you may need to do `pip uninstall setuptools`. Setuptools is pretty difficult to upgrade actually, though I think it's possible to force a deletion then install it with pip. Anaconda is way easier, but if you don't want  anaconda, you can create a virtualenv (`pip install virtualenv`) and install it there instead.

Comment: I wound up installing Anaconda from the website.